# Getting Error generating libspec: Initializing library 'Shop' with no arguments failed in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am new to Robot Framework and I am trying to import python custom library file named "Shop.py" saved in CustomeLibrary folder. I am getting this error in pycharm IDE.
I am getting below error on this line "Library     ../CustomeLibrary/Shop.py"

[image]

Getting below error:

```
Unresolved library: ../CustomeLibrary/Shop.py. Error generating libspec: Initializing library 'Shop' with no arguments failed: RobotNotRunningError: Cannot access execution context.
```

[image]

Below is the python custom library file:

```
from robot.api.deco import library, keyword
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
from SeleniumLibrary import SeleniumLibrary


@library
class Shop:
    # method name will be converted to keyword
    def __init__(self):
        self.selLib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance("SeleniumLibrary")

    @keyword
    def add_items_to_cart_and_checkout(self, productsList):
        i = 1
        productsTitles = self.selLib.get_webelements("xpath://*[@class='card-title']")
        for productsTite in productsTitles:
            if productsTitle.text in productsList:
                self.selLib.click_button("xpath:(//*[@class='card-footer'])["+str(i)+"]/button")

            i = i + 1
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

- **Other details:**
  python version = python 3.10.1
  Robot Framework 6.0.1
  pip 22.3.1
  robotframework-seleniumlibrary  6.0.0

I am trying to import the python custom library file in robot framework using
"Library   ../CustomeLibrary/Shop.py"

and I am getting below error:
Unresolved library: ../CustomeLibrary/Shop.py. Error generating libspec: Initializing library 'Shop' with no arguments failed: RobotNotRunningError: Cannot access execution context

I am expecting that Shop.py should get successfully imported and i should be able to us the robot custom keyword
"Add items to cart and checkout"

Comment: I see another potential issue in your code, the moment you click on the button, all the references in your `productsTitles` will be stale and you will receive `StaleElementException`. So please fix the code to either get the product titles every time after clicking on the button or use other strategies to overcome the stale element exception.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar problem is described [here](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/2345).

In order to obtain keyword names your `__init__` is executed. Inside it you are trying to get instance of built-in library of running robotframework, but robot isn't running (check exception name).

You could replace `self.selLib` with property so your code could look something like that:

```py
from robot.api.deco import library, keyword
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
from SeleniumLibrary import SeleniumLibrary


@library
class Shop:

    @property
    def selLib(self):
        return BuiltIn().get_library_instance("SeleniumLibrary")

    @keyword
    def add_items_to_cart_and_checkout(self, productsList):
        i = 1
        productsTitles = self.selLib.get_webelements("xpath://*[@class='card-title']")
        for productsTitle in productsTitles:
            if productsTitle.text in productsList:
                self.selLib.click_button("xpath:(//*[@class='card-footer'])["+str(i)+"]/button")

            i = i + 1
```

Comment: Thank for the answer. This issue has been resolved after making above suggested changes and i am able to proceed.